# How to drag PopupWindow in android？

Tags: android, popupwindow

Now I write a drag function, when drag again it will move from original position.

When I press the PopupWindow’s button and move, it can realize the whole PopupWindow move. Initialization is the position of Gravity.BOTTOM.

The first time that is because window is in this position. So the move is right. But the second time, when click the button and begin to move, it suddenly jump to the first position then move.

What’s this problem?

```
private void createPopup()
{
    LayoutInflater flater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = flater.inflate(R.layout.pop, null);

    view.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch(action)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    lastX = (int)event.getRawX();
                    lastY = (int)event.getRawY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int dx = (int)event.getRawX() - lastX;
                    int dy = (int)event.getRawY() - lastY;
                    popup.update(dx, dy, -1, -1);

                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    popup = new PopupWindow(view, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setFocusable(false);
    popup.setTouchable(true);
    popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    //popup.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.ding), 100, 100);
    popup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.button1), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

    //
    popup.update();
}
```